# Why htop shows 48 sleeping processes while "show processlist" shows none? (MySQL 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)

Tags: mysql, htop

SHOW PROSSESLIST shows exactly no sleeping processes. But Htop does: I got about 48 sleeping /usr/sbin/mysqld processes with high values of VIRT 15.2G and RES 6199M.

What's going on there? Why these processes aren't listed in PROCESSLIST? Is it safe to kill them via Htop?

Comment: Were you _connected_ as root (or other `SUPER` user) when you ran the `SHOW`?

Answer (score 1):

Does the account you use to execute the `show processlist` statement have enough privileges to show any processes that belong to users other than your own  ?

Also consider at the OS level (background) MySQL processes and threads need to run even when MySQL is not actively processing any queries.  You might look at the threads table in MySQL to see those.

So killing what you see in htop is bad idea.

Comment: thank you for your Answer. I'm using sudo mysql so I would expect to have enough privileges, or do I miss something? 
Htop shows "mysql" as user of all of the processes. Is it possible that with root privileges I cannot see mysql's processes in the processlist?  Meanwhile the Values for VIRT went up from 15.2G to 15.6G :(

Comment: `sudo mysql` is useless -- unless you have `GRANTed` permissions to "mysql", which is unlikely.  You need to connect as mysql's "root", not the OS's "root".